# How would one add items to the beginning of an array with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've been searching for a while to add items to the beginning of an array with lodash. Unfortunately I can't seem to find anything other than lodash concat *(to the end of the array)*. The [docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) don't seem to say anything about it either.

I got the following code:

```js
const [collection, setCollection] = useState({
  foo: [1, 2, 3]
});

const addToCollection = (key, items) => {
  setCollection(prevCollection => ({
   ...prevCollection,
   [key]: _.concat(prevCollection[key] || [], items)
  }));
};
```

But this concats all the items to the end. *I don't want to sort them every time because that uses unnessecary processing power, I would much rather just add them to the beginning because the API always pushes the items already sorted*

How would I accomplish this:

```js
addToCollection('foo', [4, 5, 6]);
console.log(collection['foo']) // [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3];
```

Instead of what is happening now:

```js
addToCollection('foo', [4, 5, 6]);
console.log(collection['foo']) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

Comment: `const arr = [1,2,3]; const update = [4,5,6]; arr.unshift(...update); console.log(arr);`

Comment: This can be done without loadash as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try swapping the arguments:

```
_.concat(items, prevCollection[key] || [])
```

Comment: oh, oops.. such an easy fix - this worked like a charm lol

Answer (score -1):

Or vanilla JS is pretty easy too:

```
Collection.unshift('addMe', var, 'otherString' )
```

[https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp#:~:text=The%20unshift()%20method%20adds,use%20the%20push()%20method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp#:%7E:text=The%20unshift()%20method%20adds,use%20the%20push()%20method).

I know you asked for lodash but I figured this is a good thing to be aware of too :)

EDIT:

To clarify, this works the same whether you're pushing defined vars, string, arrays, objects or whatever:

```
let yourArray = [1,2,3];
let pushArray = [1,2,3,4];
let anotherArray = [7,8,9];
yourArray.unshift(pushArray, anotherArray);
```

will push "pushArray" and "anotherArray" to the begining of "yourArray" so it's values will look like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4], [7,8,9], 1,2,3]
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: and how do you do it with an array? You hardcoded the arguments in unshift